# How to count number of rows with a specific string value in a column using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas column with `dtype 'object'` that contains numeric values and the value `'?'`.

How should I proceed to count the number of rows that have the value `'?'` ?

I'm trying to run:

```
question_mark_count = df['column'].str.contains('\?').sum()
```

in a column that has numeric value and some question marks '?', but I'm getting the error:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

When I run `df.dtypes`, I can see that the column is `'object' type`.

I've also tried to convert the column to string:

```
df["column"] = df["column"].astype("string")
```

But I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Should you not use `.astype(‘int’)`  instead?

Comment: it won't work because I also have 0.0 values. It throws `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.0'`

Comment: Did you try my example below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to further explore possibilities:

```
df["column"].str.contains('\?').value_counts()
```

immune to `np.nan pd.NA ints floats` or whatever you have in your `df['column']`

Answer (score 1):

how about this?

```
>>> (df["column"].str.contains('\?')).astype('int').sum()
```

Comment: I got a `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`. Is is possible to concatenate a command to get rid of the NaN values as well in your proposed solution?

Comment: This is because you probably have NaN in ‘column’. Get rid of it first & then apply the solution above. It should work

Comment: df_concatenated['column'].isnull().any() returns `false` .

Comment: NaN != null. Also chec eliu’s solution with value_counts()

Answer (score 0):

In my case the previous answer is almost correct. Try to add *na=False* in the call to the contains function:

```
df["column"].str.contains('\?', na=False).astype('int').sum()
```